# How to change the query string value from string url in c# generated by system

Tags: c#

I have string URL as follow 
http://localhost:56856/s.aspx?&searchString=jacket&sortField=&pageNumber=2&pageSize=0&facetQuery=

I need to change the query string values from the above url for example if i find the pageSize=0 than i need to change its value pageNumber*12.
like in above url pagnumber is 2 and page size is 0 so page size should be 2* 12=24. i have used following code

```
string url=http://localhost:56856/s.aspx?&searchString=jacket&sortField=&pageNumber=2&pageSize=0&facetQuery=
    var QueryValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);
                string pageno = QueryValues.Get("pageNumber");
                string pagesize = QueryValues.Get("pageSize");
                if (pagesize == "0")
                {
                    QueryValues.Set("pageSize", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(pageno) * 12));
            }
```

in QueryValues i am getting url like this =http://localhost:%%2f55%/s%aspx?&searchString=jacket&sortField=&pageNumber=2&pageSize=0&facetQuery=

can you please suggest me where i am wrong and how can i convert this QueryValues to valid url?

Thanks

Comment: And?....  what's happening?

Comment: What's `webQuery.querystringreplace`?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you encountered? As it stands this reads like a "i need this done, please do it for me" question, which SO isnt the right place for.

Comment: @JohnRW -- You're not quite right... it isn't a "*please* do it for me"...  more like just a "do it for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I noticed is that you are not identifying what the querystring prior to parsing it. We can easily find this by locating the `IndexOf('?')` in the URL which delineates the URL from the QueryString. You may want to review the [MSDN: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) article, I used their identification method when I was reviewing this method ( I generally use more primitve methods when working with URLs)

Be aware that the  `NameValueCollection` QueryString can have and will return  *null* values in it.

I recommend that when retrieving these values that you take appropriate countermeasures, such as setting strings to empty or numbers to 0. I further recommend that you do these upon retrieval and not using compounded `Convert.To\

```
 string url = @"http://localhost:56856/s.aspx?&searchString=jacket&sortField=&pageNumber=2&pageSize=0&facetQuery=";

 #region ===== Added: Identify and split =====
 int iqs = url.IndexOf('?');
 if iqs< 0) {
      // Cannot process, NO query string present
      // Corrective Action?
 } else {
      string urlQS= (iqs < url.Length - 1) ? currurl.Substring(iqs + 1) : String.Empty;
 #endregion ===================================

      var QueryValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlQS); // changed from (url)

      string pageno = QueryValues.Get("pageNumber"); // catch null return ""
      string pagesize = QueryValues.Get("pageSize"); // int, catch null return 0

      if (pagesize == "0") {
           QueryValues.Set( "pageSize", Convert.ToString( Convert.ToInt32(pageno) * 12 ) );
      } 

 }
```

Comment: I have used the following code to make valid URL and my problem is solved                                                                                                        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?")));
                    uriBuilder.Query = QueryValues.ToString();
                    url = uriBuilder.ToString();